# Настройки для каждого пользователя NSUserDefaults. Spritekit. Swift

Tags: ios, разработка-игр, swift, spritekit

Пишу игру на свифте. Хочу сделать что-то вроде логинов,  можно будет выбрать уже созданный, либо создать новый. Настройки должны сохраняться для каждого такого логина отдельно. через что лучше делать? ( сейчас делаю через NSUserDefaults). И как это лучше организовать?

Comment: Думаю, лучше всего добавлять к строке ключа id игрока. Например, ключ в NSUserDefaults лучшего счета игрока KEVIN будет выглядеть так "KEVIN_highScore".

Answer (score 1):

Данные по игроку хранятся в словаре. Ключем для NSUserDefaults будет являться мыло или id пользователя.
Также отдельно хранится массив этих клюй (чтоб сохранился порядок пользователей, если он нужен).